# Rotate image if width is greater than height

Tags: bash, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have a few thousand rectangular images of various sizes. I want them all to have a longer height than a width. I want to do this by rotating all images whose height is shorter than their width 90 degrees. How do I do this with imagemagick?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple function like below, to getting the width &height of the image then check if w>h then rotate it.

```
rotate() {
    (( $(identify -format '%w > %h' "$1") )) && convert "$1" -rotate 90 "rotated_$1"; 
}
```

Call it like `rotate image.png`.

---

Another approach which is suggested and presented by [user414777](/414777/user414777) using [exif](https://exiftool.org/) tool, that is doing the rotation based on the [EXIF Orientation tags](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html):

```
exif -co rotated_"$1" --ifd=0 --tag=0x0112 --set-value=6 "$1"
```

Switches explanations:

```
TagID    TagName       Writable  Group   Values/Notes
0x0112   Orientation   int16u    IFD0    1 = Horizontal (normal)
                                         2 = Mirror horizontal
                                         3 = Rotate 180
                                         4 = Mirror vertical
                                         5 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 270 CW
                                         6 = Rotate 90 CW
                                         7 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 90 CW
                                         8 = Rotate 270 CW
```

Comment: With jpeg files, just changing their exif [orientation](http://jpegclub.org/exif_orientation.html) tag may be enough, which would be order of magnitude faster than physically rotating the image. Eg. `exif -co new.jpg --ifd=0 --tag=0x0112 --set-value=6 old.jpg`

Comment: And changing the `IFS`, creating an array, is a bit of overkill. With bash/ksh/zsh, you can do just `un_landscape(){ (( $(identify -format '%w > %h' "$1") )) && convert "$1" -rotate 90 "rotated_$1"; }`. This, of course, just in your answer, assuming they don't *already* have an exif orientation tag, in which case the width/height will have no relationship to the way in which they're displayed ;-)

Comment: good suggestion and golfed version, I will update in my answer later if you don't mind. thanks